# Changing default theme give Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader in opencart

Tags: opencart

Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "common/column_left.twig" (looked into: C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/retail/upload/catalog/view/theme). in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\upload\system\library\template\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php:215 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\upload\system\library\template\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php(139): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('common/column_l...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\upload\system\library\template\Twig\Environment.php(312): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('common/column_l...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\upload\system\library\template\Twig\Environment.php(378): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('common/column_l...', NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\upload\system\library\template\twig.php(33): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('common/column_l...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\upload\system\library\template.php(51): Template\Twig->render('common/column_l...', '1') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\uploa in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\retail\upload\system\library\template\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php on line 215

How to fix it. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Could be of help

Twig has caching, which is super annoying when you're developing. You can turn off the caching by going to the admin Dashboard area, and clicking the gear icon in the upper-right corner. You can turn the caching off (and refresh it) in there.

put your original file back and clear the TWIG Cache

This Solution from opencart : https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=186585

Comment: I have done all these steps but still, it's not solved.Is there any other setting I need to modify? Thnks in advance